# How to install and use bitmap .pcf fonts on debian jessie?

Tags: fonts, bitmap, debian

I'm running on GNU/Linux Debian Jessie and I would like to use a bitmap font with .pcf extension.
The bitmap font is ohsnap and you can find it here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/osnapfont/

My steps for installing the font are the following:

- Donwload and install the font in /usr/share/fonts/ folder.
- Execute mkfondir and mkfontscale command in the font folder.
- Remove the symbolic link 70-no-bitmaps.conf in /etc/fonts/conf.d/ folder.
- Run dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig-config and choose yes to the third question.
- Run dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig.

And this my ~/.xinitrc file when I type startx on the login shell:

```
xset b off
xset +fp /usr/share/fonts/ohsnap-1.8.0
xset fp rehash
xset r rate 200 50
xset m 3/2 3
xset dpms 0 0 300
xsetroot -cursor_name left_ptr
xrdb -load ~/.Xresources
numlockx on
feh --bg-fill '/home/nbl/.wallpapers/wallpaper-1.jpg' --no-feh &
mpd

if [ -z `xrandr | grep " connected" | grep "HDMI3"` ]; then
   echo "No second monitor found"
else
   xrandr --output HDMI1 --right-of HDMI3
fi

sleep 2
exec ck-launch-session dbus-launch xmonad
```

So I can use ohsnap with xterm but I can't with gedit or dzen2 whereas on Wheezy I can.

Thank you a lot for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Debian 8 is only recognizing bitmap fonts with file extension ".pcf.gz" not ".pcf" anymore. You may want to cd into the ohsnap folder and `gzip *.pcf`

Comment: Thank you very much, I love you guy, just one question how did you find that debian recongizing only bitmap fonts whit ".pcf.gz" ? I didn't find anything on internet.

Comment: Couldn't find anything on web either, besides your question. However, bitmap fonts were enabled and working but not ohsnap anymore so I wondered why and finally compared the filenames. I've just tried to gzip and it worked, but don't ask me why ;)

Comment: I know this is old now but just incase anyone has the same problem version 2.5.4 of the freetype library has a bug which was fixed in 2.5.5 which meant the library would not read uncompressed pcf files. `FreeType 2.5.5 has been released. This is a minor bug fix release: All users of PCF fonts should update, since version 2.5.4 introduced a bug that prevented reading of such font files if not compressed.`

Comment: @tribeca Thank you for the info. :)